# Hosting a UserControl as Tab Content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I am having a problem when attempting to host a UserControl as Tab Content within a Tab Item in a TabControl.

My code is structured as follows:

I have a view model which is supposed to be rendered into a View via a DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyViewModel}">
  <Views:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to present this view in
   a TabControl (actually a
   XamTabControl, but either way, the
   issue remains.)

```
   <UserControl>
        <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>              
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyViewModel}">
              <Views:MyView />
            </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="Controls:TabItemEx">
          <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
          <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
                  Value="{DynamicResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                  Value="{DynamicResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>                   
      </UserControl.Resources>
      <Grid >
       <Controls:XamTabControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemContainerStyle}"
        TabStripPlacement="Left"
        TabLayoutStyle="SingleRowAutoSize"
        AllowTabClosing="True"                               
        Grid.Row="1"
        TabItemCloseButtonVisibility="WhenSelectedOrHotTracked">
        </Controls:XamTabControl>
      </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

The issue is that the content does not render.  The Tab header does render fine, however, there is no content in the tabs.

I am fairly certain the issue lies within the View/Viewmodel mapping as when I change the templates to the following, I do get content rendered:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate">
  <Ellipse Fill="Green"/>
</DataTemplate>
<Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="Controls:TabItemEx">
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
          Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
  <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
          Value="{StaticResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an awful lot of work to reproduce your scenario with the given code - perhaps you can reduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.  the BAML was corrupted due to a re-name operation! :(

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correct, then i think the problem is that you try to bind properties from the VM to the view

```
  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>                    
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">                       
            <StackPanel>                       
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />                       
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>                                     
            </StackPanel>                       
    </DataTemplate>
```

and concurrently you try with the same binding to "replace" the VM with the view

```
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>                            
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyViewModel}">                             
          <Views:MyView />                             
      </DataTemplate>
```

In your second example you don't map the vm to the view with the same binding, so you see the green ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work with MyView.xaml as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication27.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

Comment: you have managed to make what work?  The issue is rendering a usercontrol into a tabcontrol content pane in an MVVM manner.

Comment: sorry but that is not the same.  I am using a DataTemplate to map a view model to a view.